# How refresh all values in a datagrid column?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid in binding, composed with a single column and a button.

When I click on this button "Select All", all values in the column have changed.

What's the problem ? I'd see the result immediately without datagrid scroll.

How can I make an immediate refresh of the column?

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Ele_Soc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Selec_Elenc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    SelectionMode="Single"  Name="Dg_Dat" >

    <DataGrid.Columns>                
          <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_Soc_cod" Binding="{Binding Soc_cod}" 
                             IsReadOnly="True" Header="Soc. Cod"  Width="80" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
public ObservableCollection<Model_Soc> Ele_Soc { get; set; }
private void Cmd_SelectAll()
{
    for (Int32 i = 0; i <= Ele_Soc.Count - 1; i++) {
        Ele_Soc.Item(i).Soc_cod = "Yes";
        OnPropertyChanged("Ele_Soc");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't work ! :-(

Comment: How about `OnPropertyChanged("Soc_cod");` ? You changing Soc_cod property value so try to rise its changed event.

Comment: I tryed with   
OnPropertyChanged("Soc_cod") and OnPropertyChanged("Ele_Soc") but doesn't work

Comment: Does you Soc_cod property have OnPropertyChanged call on setter?

Comment: Yes private string _Soc_cod { get; set; }
public string Soc_cod {
 get { return _Soc_cod; }
 set {
  _Soc_cod = value;
  OnPropertyChanged("Soc_cod");
 }
}

Comment: Add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the Text-Binding in you `DataGridTextColumn`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your idea, but i must to scroll the grid for display of new values. I think my solution is the best. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

After "For" cycle I added this code

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i <= Ele_Soc.Count - 1; i++) 
{
    Ele_Soc.Item(i).Soc_cod = "Yes";
    OnPropertyChanged("Ele_Soc");
}

ObservableCollection<Model_Soc> Tmp = Ele_Soc;
Ele_Soc = null;

OnPropertyChanged("Ele_Soc");
Ele_Soc= Tmp;
OnPropertyChanged("Ele_Soc");
```